# VBA Array Public, how to pass it onto the macro calling it?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

So, I am trying to keep the code tidier by splitting 2 macros.

The first one constructed 2x 2-dimensional array for use in the 2nd macro. I have already declare those 2 array as global, with Public statement.

But they are still no passing through to the 2nd macro after the Call statement.  I used the Watches to monitor those arrays, they got cleared out right after the Call statement.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Yes!! You are missing something.  Code examples!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the array public or global. Pass the array from the first to the second.

```
sub first()
    dim i as long, j as long, arr as variant

    redim arr(0 to 1, 0 to 1)

    for i=lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)
        for j=lbound(arr, 2) to ubound(arr, 2)
            arr(i, j) = i*j
        next j
    next i

    second arr

end sub

sub second(vals as variant)
    dim i as long, j as long

    for i=lbound(vals, 1) to ubound(vals, 1)
        for j=lbound(vals, 2) to ubound(vals, 2)
            debug.print vals(i, j)
        next j
    next i

end sub
```